# Another module not found error for django-docs

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am running a Cookiecutter django app. Now I want to integrate django-docs (https://pypi.org/project/django-docs/). I am fairly sure that I am doing it correctly since I am just copy and pasting from the documentation. After installing it I build my docker image anew and run my server.

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docs.urls'
```

My process was like this:

1) Add app to base requirements
`django-docs==0.3.1 # https://github.com/littlepea/django-docs`

2) Add it to my apps in my config file

```
    ...
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_framework',
    'docs',
    ....
```

3) Rebuild docker image

```
docker-compose -f local.yml build
```

4) Then I added this to my urls which throws me the error: 
`url(r'^docs/', include('docs.urls')),`

I also tried `path('docs/', include('docs.urls')),`

Is there anything I am missing? THe other SO questions didn't solve my problem.

Thanks for any help! Very much appreciated!

EDIT:

I also did:

```
DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../doc/_build/html') 
DOCS_ACCESS = 'staff'
```

Comment: Looking at the quick start guide, it looks like you only performed 3 out of the 4 steps. `DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../docs/_build/html')` is required. See https://django-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation Not sure if that fixes it, but worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks orangeInk. I did this, sorry I forgot to add it to my question. In my settings I have ```DOCS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../doc/_build/html')```
```DOCS_ACCESS = 'staff'```  It also shouldn't be responsible for the import error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the `django-docs` library is correctly installed and the `docs` module can be imported:

```
$ docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py shell
...
>>> import docs
```

If this raises an error, it might give you a hint what went wrong. If it can be imported, check that it is actually the `django-docs` library and not some conflicting module:

```
>>> docs.__file__
```

Comment: fantastic idea! Thanks Daniel. I can import it in the shell without a problem. The second comand gives me ```'/app/docs/__init__.py'``` as output.... So I guess that means there is no conflict? Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: But now I realize that I have a folder that is called docs in my project...... That is probably the conflicting module..... But how could I fix this (since I need this folder)

Comment: Exactly, this is the conflicting directory. You can try removing the `__init__.py` file, though I'm not sure if it is necessary. If that breaks anything, you have to rename the directory. Note that you have configured `doc` in your `DOCS_ROOT`.